# Select the previous rows and obtain the total of the sum of a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to apply dynamic sum on multiple selection in a jQuery Datatables table but I have bugs crashing me.
I applied prevAll() to select from the selected row plus all the previous rows, and so far everything is ok, but the sum makes me on all the previous values except the clicked one and if I change the selection by clicking further up or down the row sum goes wrong.

below is my js/jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#tableFatture').DataTable();
    var sum = 0;
    $('#tableFatture tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            sum = eval(sum + "-(" + t.cell(this, 4).data() + ")");
        } else {
            sum = 0;
            $(this).prevAll().addClass('selected');        
            t.rows('.selected').every(function(rowIdx) {
                sum = eval(sum + "+(" + t.row(rowIdx).data()[4] + ")");
            });
        }
                   
        $('#totParz').text('Tot. Selezionato: ' + sum.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

I would like it to add the sum from the selected row up and if I change the selection it will update the sum

Comment: Can you share your table #tableFatture with some data on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution.
Add input checkbox and modify js code like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var t = $('#tableFatture').DataTable();
  var sum = 0;
  $('#tableFatture tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if (this.checked) {
      $(row).prevAll().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
      sum = 0;
      $("input:checked").each(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        sum += parseFloat(t.cell(row, 4).data());
      });
    } else {
      sum -= t.cell(row, 4).data();
    }
    console.log(sum)
    $('#totParz').text('Totale: ' + sum.toFixed(2)+'€');
  });
});
```

Comment: While we do encourage - and appreciate - self answered questions, the question itself must still be open for all users to answer. Unfortunately, without the `#tableFatture` and associated relevant elements we haven't got enough information for anyone else to understand, or reproduce, your problem.